# Nested relation of the same type

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation) relations could be referenced to Pojo classes only. How to define nested dependency of the same type?

```
@Entity(tableName = "humans")
data class Human {

   @Relation
   val children:List<Human>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://medium.com/@toddcookevt/android-room-storing-lists-of-objects-766cca57e3f9) Medium blog post you can use type converter to convert list to string and vice versa.

```
class HumanTypeConverters {

    private var gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToHumanObjectList(data: String?): List<Human> {
        if (data == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList()
        }
        return gson.fromJson(data, object : TypeToken<List<Human>>() {}.type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun humanObjectListToString(humanObjects: List<Human>): String = gson.toJson(humanObjects)
}
```

and add this annotation as follows

```
@Database(entities = [Human::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(HumanTypeConverters::class)
abstract class HumanDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    ...
}
```